# Is there any way to record my game rendered by using opengles 1.1 into a video with MediaCodec?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec

I am coding a game with opengles, now, I want to record some frames when playing. My current solution is after rending the game, I use the "glReadPixels" to get the RGBA buffer of the part I need and convert the RGBA to YUV420Plan format or other format needed by the MediaCodec, it worked perfectly and generated h264 stream on some devices, while not all devices, because some issues [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37769). And I noticed that here is another way to recode video from opengl since 4.3, that is mEncoder.createInputSurface(), [here is a sample](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/EncodeAndMuxTest.java.txt). But I do't know how to render my game to this surface when rending the game to its own GLSurfaceView.
Could anyone give me any advice?

Answer (score 3):

The relevant example is the [Breakout recorder patch](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#BreakoutPatch), which does exactly what you want.  The idea is to create two EGL surfaces and render the scene twice.  By configuring the EGL surfaces to be shared, you can share a lot of GL objects, which makes things much easier.

The game is written for GLES 2.x, but I'd expect GLES 1.1 to work just fine.

On a Nexus 4 I'm able to get 60fps gameplay while simultaneously recording 30fps video at 720p.  I'm guessing that, with `glReadPixels()` and software conversion to YUV, your frame rates were a fair bit lower.

The other approach to game recording is to render the scene into an FBO texture, and then render the texture twice (once to the `GLSurfaceView`, once to the `MediaCodec` input surface).  Depending on the complexity and architecture of your game, this may be faster.

For either approach, you need to be on Android 4.3 (API 18), because that's when `Surface` input to `MediaCodec` was introduced.

FWIW, if all you want is to record some video for a demo, Android 4.4 added a [screen recording](http://bigflake.com/screenrecord/) command for developers.

**Update:** You can now find an example of recording OpenGL ES in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  The `RecordFBOActivity` does it in a couple different ways.

Comment: Hi fadden, Thank you very much, I've tried this example, it generated the video as expected. I have another question, in this sample, the audio is not recorded, and in my game, my audio is from wav(PCM format) file, is there any quick API to add my wav audio track to the muxer?

Comment: The idea is to create a second `MediaCodec` encoder for the audio, configure an additional track in the `MediaMuxer`, and then just submit data for both.  One of the CTS tests (http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#MediaMuxerTest) has code that generates an audio+video output file.

Comment: Hi fadden, I tried to add 'audio/raw' track directly, while it seems MPEG4Writer does not support. And I also tried using the MediaCodec to encode it, while I got troubles with MediaCodec, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768695/omx-google-aac-encoder-do-not-work-in-mediacodec-when-encode-pcm-to-aac), do you have any sample doing this?

Comment: I haven't worked with audio.  The `MediaMuxerTest` code uses the `audio/mp4a-latm` MIME type.  Have you tried that instead?